# Nuxt vuex - moving store from Vue

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, vuex

I have been fiddling with moving a tutorial I did in Vue to Nuxt.  I have been able to get everything working, however I feel I'm not doing it the "proper way".  I have added the Nuxt axios module, but wasnt able to get it working, so I ended up just using the usual axios npm module.  Here is my store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

export const state = () => ({
  events: []
})

export const mutations = {
  setEvents: (state, events) => {
    state.events = events
  }
}

export const actions = {
  loadEvents: async context => {
    let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/events';
    const response = await axios.get(uri)
    context.commit('setEvents', response.data)
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to re-write this store using the @nuxtjs/axios module.  I also didnt think I'd need to import vuex here, but if I dont, my app doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [@nuxtjs/axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) module, you can configure axios inside your nuxt.config.js:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  axios: {
    // proxy: true
  }
}
```

You can use it inside your store (or components) with `this.$axios`

```js
// In store
{
  actions: {
    async getIP ({ commit }) {
      const ip = await this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
      commit('SET_IP', ip)
    }
  }
}
```